# The Jacobi identity of a Lie algebra?

Tags: lie-algebras, quantum-groups

Let $g$ be a finite dimensional real Lie algebra and $(,)$ be a nondegenerate invariant symmetric bilinear form on $g$. Let $r\in g\bigotimes g$ be a skew-symmetric solution of the MCYBE. We may regard $r$ as a linear map $g^{\star}\mapsto g$, and hence as a linear map $\rho: g\rightarrow g$,identifying $g^{\star}$ with $g$ by using the inner product.
   $\mathbf{Proposition}$: With the above notation, let $r\in g\otimes g$ be a skew symmetric solution of the MCYBE and define, for $X,Y\in g$, $[X,Y]_{r}=[\rho(X),Y]+[X,\rho(Y)]$. Then $[,]_{r}$ is a Lie bracket on $g$.

I have checked it, but I have problems in proving the Jacobi identity. Can anyone tell me how to prove the Jacobi identity or if there are any useful properties of the linear map $\rho$? Thank you.

Comment: what is the MCYBE?

Comment: @Giulio the MCYBE is the modified classical Yang-Baxter equation

Comment: could you provide a link for the definition you use for MCYBE? or, even better, include the definition?

Comment: @YCor I am reading this book "a guide to quantum groups" written by V.C and A.P. Maybe you can see page 54 and 71 for these things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write the modified CYBE as $B_R(x,y)+\lambda [x,y]=0$ with 
$$
B_R(x,y):=[R(x),R(y)]-R([R(x),y]+[x,R(y)]),
$$
and $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$. Then
note that the bracket $[x,y]_R:=[R(x),y]+[x,R(y)]$ satisfies the Jacobi identity if and only if
$$
[B_R(x,y),w]+[B_R(y,w),x]+[B_R(w,x),y]=0
$$
for all $x,y,w\in \mathfrak{g}$.

Comment: Sorry,I don't have much knowledge of the MCBYE. In my mind, the MCYBE is this pattern $[[r,r]]=-\omega$, where $\omega$ is a canonical $g-$invariant element of ${\wedge}^3 g$. How do you write it as $B_R(x,y)+\lambda[x,y]=0$?

Comment: See [Kupershmidt's article](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9910188) and [this reference](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01076717#page-1) by Semenov-Tyan-Shanskii, in particular euqation $(12)$.

Comment: @ Dietrich Burde  Ok. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Kupershmidt's article abstract:  https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9910188 ; on MSN http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1722068 ; (non-free) journal article http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.2991/jnmp.1999.6.4.5 .